# Copying cells based on input box - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 files, one with the complete data (input.xlsx) and another(Final Report.xlsm) where it needs to be copied into. In input.xlsx column A has dates and Col E has a list of names.

What I am trying to do is to copy cells (through a macro) from 'input.xlsx' based on two criterias. My criteria is a date (in col A) and a list of names(in col E).

I have tried the code below. I am running this code from Final Report.xlsm and it works fine but what I need is to be able to input date by a message box rather than hardcode it and similarly the names as well would be in the Column A of sheet3 in Final Report.xlsm. It needs to pick the criteria through message box for date and names from Column A of sheet3 as the names keep changing and there are more than 100 names.

Please let me know how this code can be modified.

My Code:

```
Sub Generate()
  Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
   "E:\Resource\Input.xlsx"

  Sheets("NewInput").Select

  Range("A1").Select

  Selection.AutoFilter
  ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$49000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="3/1/2017"
  ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$49000").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="John, Henry, Jacob"
  Cells.Select
  Selection.Copy
  Windows("Final Report.xlsm").Activate
  Sheets("Sheet1").Select
  Range("A1").Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: avoid of using `Select` and `Activate` methods. See: [Excel VBA Performance Coding Best Practices](https://blogs.office.com/2009/03/12/excel-vba-performance-coding-best-practices/)

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Generate()
'declare variables
Dim srcWbk As Workbook, dstWbk As Workbook
Dim srcWsh As Worksheet, dstWsh As Worksheet
Dim sDate As String, dDate As Date
Dim i As Integer

'on error go to error handler
On Error GoTo Err_Generate

    'initiate variables
    'source workbook and worksheet
    Set srcWbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="E:\Resource\Input.xlsx")
    Set srcWsh = srcWbk.Worksheets("NewInput")
    'destination workbook and worksheet
    Set dstWbk = ThisWorkbook '=> "Final Report.xlsm
    Set dstWsh = dstWbk.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'prompt a user for date, max. 3 times
    While sDate = ""
        sDate = InputBox("Enter a date. Use 'mm/dd/yyyy' format!", "Enter date...", Date)
        If sDate <> "" Then dDate = CDate(sDate) 'this part you may want to improve. Using Regex will be very good solution!
        i = i + 1
        If i = 3 Then
            MsgBox "You canceled entering date 3. times!", vbInformation, "Info..."
            GoTo Exit_Generate
        End If
    Loop

    'filter and copy data
    srcWsh.Range("$A$1:$M$49000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=dDate
    srcWsh.Range("$A$1:$M$49000").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="John, Henry, Jacob"
    srcWsh.Cells.Copy
    dstWsh.Range("A1").Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False


Exit_Generate:
    On Error Resume Next
    'clean up
    Set srcWsh = Nothing
    If srcWbk Is Not Nothing Then srcWbk.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Set srcWbk = Nothing
    Set dstWhs = Nothing
    Set dstWbk = Nothing
    Exit Sub

Err_Generate:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, Err.Number
    Resume Exit_Generate
End Sub
```

This is very important to use code in context and provide error handling!

Note: Not tested, but it should works as well!

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this...

```
Sub Generate()
Dim wbSource As Workbook, wbDest As Workbook
Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet, wsCrit As Worksheet
Dim CritDate As String
Dim critName

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wbDest = ThisWorkbook
Set wsDest = wbDest.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set wsCrit = wbDest.Sheets("Sheet3")

'Clearing existing data on destination sheet before copying the new data from Input.xlsx
wsDest.Cells.Clear

'Assuming the Names criteria are in column A starting from Row2 on Sheet3
critName = Application.Transpose(wsCrit.Range("A2", wsCrit.Range("A1").End(xlDown)))

CritDate = InputBox("Enter a date...", "Date:", "mm/dd/yyyy")
CritDate = Format(CritDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")

If CritDate = "" Then
    MsgBox "You didn't enter a date.", vbExclamation, "Action Cancelled!"
    Exit Sub
End If

Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="E:\Resource\Input.xlsx")
Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets("NewInput")

With wsSource.Rows(1)
    .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & CritDate, Operator:=xlAnd
    .AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:=critName, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    wsSource.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy wsDest.Range("A1")
End With
wbSource.Close False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```